# Jupyter install for Python 2.7 failed

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have the Anaconda distribution of Python 2.7 and I needed to install the Jupyter notebook package. During the installation process my computer turned off and after that I couldn't continue with the process. I tried to uninstall Jupyter and try installing it again, but I keep getting the same error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda\Scripts\ipython-script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
    File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .terminal.embed import embed
    File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 19, in <module>
    from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config
    File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", line 22, in <module>
    from IPython.core.completer import IPCompleter
    File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\completer.py", line 71, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import generics
    File "C:\Users\Acer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\generics.py", line 8, in <module>
    from simplegeneric import generic
    ImportError: No module named simplegeneric
```

What should I remove/add in order to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the python package [simplegeneric](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplegeneric). After you install it, you need to install the next package that you fail to import. Continue this process until you dont get any import errors.